# complexity and number of steps in recursive fibonacci

Tags: c++, c++11, fibonacci

I have a task to make an analysis about recursive fibonacci algorithm. The algorithm has O(2^n) complexity. I have read that n is depth and in another article n is input size in 2^n. So what is the truth? Then how to count number of steps(maybe we can also call it recursive calls) to get a fibonacci number. I have a code like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

long fibonacci(long);

long jl=0;
double rt;

int main(){
    long result, number;

    scanf("%ld", &number);
    clock_t mulai = clock();
    result = fibonacci(number);
    rt =  ((double) (clock() - mulai)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Fibonacci (%ld) = %ld\n", number, result);
    printf("Jumlah langkah = %ld\n", jl);
    printf("Running Time = %.10f\n", rt);
    return 0;
}

long fibonacci(long n){
    jl++;
    if(n==0 || n==1)
        return n;
    else
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

jl in this code is number of steps(recursive calls). These are my compute example:

F(1),jl=1

F(2),jl=3

F(3),jl=5

F(5),jl=15

So, is it true or false? If false what is the correct code? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Are you trying to understand what `n` is? Are you having problems analyzing the complexity of the code? Are you trying to calculate the number of times the code runs? Consider revising the question to be clearer.

Comment: I want to trying to understand what n is and how to calculate number of steps/recursive calls

Comment: In complexity analysis, `n` is always the size of the input. Recursion depth is something you calculate from `n` to determine the complexity.

Comment: The number of steps for the computation of `Fib(n)` depends on the argument `n`. The naïve recursive approach (i.e., without memoization) is in *O(2^n)*: just compute how many steps each computation takes.

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is that if you ask for for instance `fibonacci(3)`you're going to need to make some recursive calls. To visualise we can draw a tree, `fibonacci(3)` calls `fibonacci(3 - 1)` and `fibonacci(3 - 2)` etc.

```
            fibonacci(3)   
             /      \
      fibonacci(2)  fibonacci(1)
       /      \
fibonacci(0) fibonacci(1)
```

if you need to calculate `fibonacci(4)` the tree becomes

```
                     fibonacci(4)
                     /           \
            fibonacci(3)          fibonacci(2)
             /      \               |         \
      fibonacci(2)  fibonacci(1)  fibonacci(1) fibonacci(0)
       /      \
fibonacci(0) fibonacci(1)
```

You can probably spot the pattern already, at its deepest point, the tree has depth n. Whereas the number of nodes is in O(2^n).

That is to say, if you're executing the function, you will recurse at most n levels down, but still execute ~2^n function calls.

Comment: ps Since I saw the `clock()` etc., we're talking about theoretical time complexity, not actual time. The idea is that the time `fibonacci(n)` takes to complete grows exponentially when n gets bigger.